# Open the downloaded image from Gallery app android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

Here I am trying to open an image in my emulator gallery,I can see the image once called ACTION_PICK.

My issue is once ACTION_VIEW is chosen image will not be displayed to user and returns **null**.
How can I achieve this

**Sending an intent to open up the gallery.**

```
final Intent intent = makeGalleryIntent(data.getDataString()); 
Log.d(TAG, "start gallery Activity " + data.getDataString()); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**Opening the gallery**

```
private Intent makeGalleryIntent(String pathToImageFile) {

        Log.d("", "5");  

        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" +
                 pathToImageFile), "image/*");  
               }
```

Comment: Haven't you implemented startActivityForResult?

Comment: @Harry yes I have implemented the startActivityForResult if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            // Check if the request code is what we're expecting.
          
            mResultArray.get(requestCode).execute(data);

        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            mResultArray.get(requestCode).printError(data); and I am getting the result back but cannot display it.

Comment: post code for displaying the image.

Comment: Thanks Harry - If the image is successfully downloaded into the gallery the above code should open the image but not doing it. So I don't have any other means of displaying this image.

Comment: As in your code --data.getDataString()-- If you have image path then why dont you display it directly in imageview.

Comment: Any suggestions of how this is done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75913/discussion-between-harry-and-mahad-ruush).